# Proper way to avoid parseInt throwing a NumberFormatException for input string: ""

Tags: java, string, parseint

When I run parseInt:

```
Integer.parseInt(myString);
```

it throws:

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Does this mean I have do something like this?

```
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(myString))
  return Integer.parseInt(myString);
else
 return 0;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, you could use the conditional operator instead:

```
return StringUtils.isNotBlank(myString) ? Integer.parseInt(myString) : 0;
```

If you need to do this in multiple places, you'd probably want to put this into a separate method. Note that you should also consider situations where `myString` is null, or contains non-numeric text.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, but: Wrap it in a thin method (and eliminate the redundant `else`), or use an existing implementation, like [Commons Lang's `NumberUtils.toInt(str, defaultValue)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#toInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
NumberUtils.toInt(myString, 0);
```

This method handles `null` values and conversion failures.

Writing the same thing on your own is straight-forward:

- Check for null, and/or...
- ...Wrap the `NumberFormatExtension` exception

Answer (score 9):

If the string can be empty I do it this way:

```
Integer.parseInt("0" + inputString)
```

When I'm not sure it contains only digits:

```
Integer.parseInt(0 + inputString.replaceAll("\\D+",""))
```

Comment: I might be a novice but why is this not upvoted at all, such a neat simple trick. Update, just realized why, it fails for negative values!

Comment: This tricky way only work for unsigned integer (positive number)

Comment: Correct. For general case I would use some third-party *Utils library (see other answers)

Comment: Blindly replacing non-digits can lead to unexpected behavior in the eyes of the user.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is fine, but as a coding style I prefer to make tests "positive" (`isBlank`), rather than "negative" (`isNotBlank`), ie

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(myString)) {
    return 0;
}
return Integer.parseInt(myString); // Note: No need for else when the if returns
```

or, more succinctly:

```
return StringUtils.isBlank(myString) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  (Validate your inputs before making assumptions about what are in them.  :-)

+1 for already finding Apache's common-lang w/ `StringUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(String)` doesn't accept non-numeric input, including nulls and empty strings.

Either guard against that like you suggested, or catch the NFE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why was I searching for this but here's the easy way:

```
int test=str.isEmpty()?0:Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Comment: This will throw an NPE if `str` is null.