# Java NumberFormatException stops working if caught

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

UPDATE: sorry for misleading some of you, here is more detailed code:

I'm trying to parse `String[]` array to `int[]` array. I take String from `JTextArea`, make `String[]` and then `int[]`.

```
      array1String="asd, lala, 22";
      array2String="1,2,3";

      String [] arr1 = array1String.split(",");
      String [] arr2 = array2String.split(",");

      int[] array1 = new int[arr1.length];
      for (int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
       try {
           array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            resultLabel.setText(ex.getMessage());
          }
       }

       int[] array2 = new int[arr2.length];
       for (int i=0; i<arr2.length; i++) {
           try {
              array2[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr2[i]);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
              resultLabel.setText(ex.getMessage());
           }
        }
```

the `parseInt()` method interprets any gibberish as a "0". So instead of getting an exception, I get every int[] member corresponding to gibberish String[] member as a ZERO. But that's not what I want. I want to catch the exception to pass the message to the JLabel. I don't want it to happily eat any nonsense and make it "0". Am i missing something? I suspect that is not how this is supposed to work.

result arrays look like the

```
array1 [0,0,22]
array2 [1,2,3].
```

And nothing goes to Label, as if exception never happened. By i didn't change the code, only handling the exception changed.

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't really be catching `Exception` in your catch clause, but rather `NumberFormatException` which is your expected exception in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to avoid parseInt throwing a NumberFormatException for input string: ""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780962/proper-way-to-avoid-parseint-throwing-a-numberformatexception-for-input-string)

Comment: What do you mean the `parseInt()` method interprets any 'gibberish' as 0? That is not true. It will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input `String` contains anything but digits (with the exception of a negative sign as the first character).

Comment: `x` being declared in the `try` block, how do you check that *So instead of getting an exception, I get x=0.* ? Is your test code missing something?

Comment: @Emptyfruit that clarifys quite a lot. Though this leaves you with a logical problem now: default value of `int` is 0, but there's no `undefined`-value for `int`. Simplest solution: use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` and use `null` as undefined value

Comment: @Paul I don't get the logic of exception's behaviour. Why if i'm not handling it at all - the method sees the first unsuitable for parsing letters and throws exception, but when i tell it "Ok, if this happens - say the same also here and here" it starts to think that "asd" is "0" ?

Comment: @Emptyfruit that's not exactly how this code works. If `Integer.parseInt(...)` throws an exception, the code doesn't update the value at all, thus leaving it at the default-value, which is 0. There's simply no assignment, if an exception is thrown

Comment: @Paul I get it. But how i handle the exception in a way that it aborts the program, as it does when there is no try-catch, but pass me a message?

Comment: @Emptyfruit simplest way would be to print to the message and afterwards call `System.exit(0)` to completely terminate the app. Though this will aswell close the `UI`. This is highly dependant on how you want to terminate the program and how the program itself works. If you just want to stop parsing you can simply add a `return`-statement after printing the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for int is 0. Since you get an exception and nothing is assigned to x, you get 0

Answer (score 2):

The code setting the text of the `JLabel` is missing, but I guess it's after the try-catch-block and will simply use the value of `x`, which is 0 by default. The preferable solution to this problem is to update the text inside the try-catch-block like this:

```
try{
    int x = ...
    resultLabel.setText("" + x);
}catch(Exception ex){
    resultLabel.setText(ex.getMessage());
}
```

In general, if generating data might throw an exception is recommended to process the data inside the try-catch-block the data is produced in.

EDIT:
There's one simple problem with this code: `int` doesn't have any properties like an `undefined` value. The simplest approach to this would be to use an `Integer[]` instead and `null` as `undefined`-value:

```
Integer x;
try{
    x = ...;
}catch(Excpetion ex){
    resultLabel.setText(ex.getMessage());
    x = null;
}
```

Comment: How can `resultLabel.setText("" + x);` be after the try-catch as `x` is out of scope after the try-catch?

Comment: of course i set Label text inside catch block. That is the only place i can get exception's info.

Comment: @ouah as i said in the post: "I **guess** ..." it's pretty obvious though that ops code is just a simple stub representing the actual code, since otherwise op couldn't use his code aswell.

Comment: Why you want to update the label inside CATCH block, if you do this way then you need to have duplication of code for `resultLabel.setText` - one for success  and one for failure ..

Comment: @Emptyfruit the point is not about where you set the label to display the errormessage, but where you display the value that'd be parsed from the input-string. Though it would simplify things a lot, if you posted **all relevant** code instead of a few lines

Comment: @hagrawal well, if you don't do it inside the try-catch-block, the other option would be to store a flag for whether the conversion from string to int succeeded and afterwards update the label according to this flag. Thus it's a lot more efficient and saves quite some code to simply move the code for generating the output into the try-catch-block

Comment: Why? You can simply declare a variable which you can update with either success or error message, and then in end update it to Label, right? I have used same approach in my answer.

Comment: @hagrawal this approach doesn't save any code at all as you might already have noticed looking at the code of your solution. Instead you introduce a new variable that can be spared and move the code for the output further down. guess this is rather about personal style than anything else though

Comment: I would agree with you that it is more about personal style to make code more readable, predictable and manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are using `int x = Integer.parseInt(str);` in TRY block then it means your `x` becomes local variable of your TRY block and you cannot use it outside of TRY, not even in CATCH block. So, the in case of exception, question of `x=0` will not even come because `x` would have lost its scope.

And if you are declaring `x` outside of TRY block (*so that you can use it inside CATCH or outside TRY block*) then you have initialize it (*ofcourse with value as 0 or -1*) then `x=0` or `x=-1` should be expected value of `x`

Your concern:

> I want to catch the exception to pass the message to the JLabel.

Consider below approach, where you are catching the exception, computing the error message and then passing/setting into your label field etc.

**Advantage** of this approach as opposed to other is that you need to have duplicate code of `resultLabel.setText()`, you are updating your `labelMessage` with either success message or failure message and using it.

Please feel free to let me know if this doesn't completely address your concern.

```
    String labelMessage = null;
    String str = "asd";
    try {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(str);
        labelMessage = //Whatever you want...
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        labelMessage = "Error message = " + e.getMessage();  // OR some other menaingful message you want
    }
    //Set to you label field...
```