# java.lang.NumberFormatException when clicking button

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, exception, numberformatexception

im am writing a java program of a frame that the user enters a list of numbers, in JTextFields and be stored in array elements, and when button is preseed its going to sort the arrae and set it in another JText field[image]

the problem is that when i click the button it gives an exception

```
thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Array.actionPerformed(Array.java:92)
```

knowing that the actionPerformed method has the following code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String s1= e.getActionCommand(); 
        if(s1.equals("Sort")){
            int[] a = new int[ 6]; 
            String ti1 = t1.getText();
            String ti2 = t2.getText();
            String ti3 = t3.getText();
            String ti4 = t4.getText();
            String ti5 = t5.getText();
            String ti6 = t6.getText();

            a[0] = Integer.parseInt(ti1); 
            a[1] = Integer.parseInt(ti2); 
            a[2] = Integer.parseInt(ti3); 
            a[3] = Integer.parseInt(ti4); 
            a[4] = Integer.parseInt(ti5); 
            a[5] = Integer.parseInt(ti6); 

            for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++){

            for(int j = 0; j<a.length-1;j++){ 
                if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                    int temp = a[j];
                    a[j]=a[j+1];
                    a[j+1]=temp; 
                }

                }
            }
            t7.setText(Integer.toString(a[0]));
            t8.setText(Integer.toString(a[1]));
            t9.setText(Integer.toString(a[2]));
            t10.setText(Integer.toString(a[3]));
            t11.setText(Integer.toString(a[4]));
            t12.setText(Integer.toString(a[5]));
```

Comment: Java can't turn the empty string into a number, as the exception states.

Comment: the problem is that there is no empty string entered

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780962/proper-way-to-avoid-parseint-throwing-a-numberformatexception-for-input-string

Comment: the stacktrace tells you the line in which the error occurs (`at Array.actionPerformed(Array.java:92)`), which is likely one of the `a[X] = Integer.parseInt(tiX); ` lines. Check why that `tiX` is empty.

Comment: What's the type of t<n> variables ? How are they initialized ?

Comment: I figured out the problem!! i aded the same JTextField object twice rather than adding t1 and t10 ive added t1 twice thats why t10 was empty

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem!! i aded the same JTextField object twice to the frame, rather than adding t1 and t10 ive added t1 twice thats why t10 was empty when i tried to use it